# Issue with DocType declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dtd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace &nbsp; with &#160; in an html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676783/how-to-replace-nbsp-with-160-in-an-html-file)

I am using the following `DTD` in my html document. But when the page renders in the browser the last 2 characters `]>`, visible in the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ] />
```

Can anybody please tell me whats wrong with this declaration ?

Comment: Why do you use a DTD in 2012 ? Just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Why are you trying to redeclare an entity that already exists?

Comment: @BoltClock - presumably because `&nbsp;` doesn't exist in XML, so its use in mark-up that claims to be XHTML will fail in a validator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [validator](http://validator.w3.org) will show that you have a syntax error in the Doctype declaration. Take the `/` off the end. It is not a self-closing element tag.

Also note that, in text/html at least, browsers have a very odd relationship with SGML and XML treating Doctypes as magic strings to determine Quirks/Standards mode rather then for their intended purpose. I wouldn't customise DTDs outside of application/xhtml+xml myself.

Comment: but after removing / at the end, the ]> characters are still visible

Comment: @user1740381 — Are you serving the document as `application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: no i am not serving the document as application/xhtml+xml

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this kind of thing anymore.

Simply use

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

to let your document be interpreted as HTML5.

See [this presentation from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5)

Comment: What XHTML nightmare? XHTML 2.0 never even made it into the standard, nobody uses XHTML 1.1, and XHTML 1.0 has gotten by just fine...

Comment: ...and XHTML5 works just fine too.